# Apache 2.4 and LDAP. Basic authentication issues

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4, ldap, svn

I'm using CentOS 8 Stream + Apache 2.4 + Subversion.

I want to allow access to SVN only for users who belong to a specific LDAP group (svn-users).

I have the following problems.

---

**case 1. Enter the correct ID / PW as an LDAP user belonging to svn-users**

This works as expected.

This user can access SVN.

---

**case 2. Enter the correct ID / PW as an LDAP user that does not belong to svn-users**

This does not work as expected.

I expected this user can't access SVN, but in reality it can.

---

**case3. Enter the wrong LDAP ID / PW**

500 Internal Server Error occurs.

For browsers, the Basic authentication dialog does not reappear and the user must restart the browser.

---

I want to solve cases 2 and 3.

Can anyone help me?

My config and log are below.

## /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
[root@my-redmine conf]# cat httpd.conf | egrep -v "^\s*#|^$"
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/subversion.conf
[root@my-redmine conf]#
```

## /etc/httpd/conf,d/subversion.conf

```
[root@my-redmine conf.d]# cat subversion.conf | egrep -v "^\s*#|^$"
<Location /svn/svn-test>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /usr/local/svn/svn-test
    LogLevel debug

    AuthLDAPBindDN <MyAdmin>
    AuthLDAPBindPassword <MyAdminPassword>
    LDAPReferrals off
    AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repository(LDAP)"
    AuthBasicAuthoritative off
    AuthUserFile /dev/null
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /usr/local/svn/svn-test/authzsvn.conf
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
    AuthLDAPUrl ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
    Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local
</Location>
[root@my-redmine conf.d]#
```

## module include

```
[root@my-redmine conf.d]]# httpd -t -M | grep auth
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authnz_ldap_module (shared)
 authz_svn_module (shared)
[root@my-redmine conf.d]]#
```

## case 1 error_log

```
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:43.046463 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195900:tid 140586535274240] [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Access granted: - GET (null)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:43.046514 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586535274240] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:43.046519 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586535274240] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.339879 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.339918 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.339927 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343581 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343608 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Access granted: 'svnuser' GET (null)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343845 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343852 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343858 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343869 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343876 2021] [authz_svn:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c(450): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Path to authz file is /usr/local/svn/svn-test/authzsvn.conf
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343905 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Access granted: 'svnuser' GET svn-test:/branches
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343929 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343942 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343946 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343953 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343958 2021] [authz_svn:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c(450): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Path to authz file is /usr/local/svn/svn-test/authzsvn.conf
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343961 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Access granted: 'svnuser' GET svn-test:/tags
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343974 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343977 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343980 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343987 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343991 2021] [authz_svn:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c(450): [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Path to authz file is /usr/local/svn/svn-test/authzsvn.conf
[Tue Jul 20 21:56:45.343994 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195900:tid 140586518488832] [client 192.168.100.120:61050] Access granted: 'svnuser' GET svn-test:/trunk
```

## case 2 error_log

```
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:46.345179 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195900:tid 140586577237760] [client 192.168.100.120:61657] Access granted: - GET (null)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:46.345227 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586577237760] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61657] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:46.345231 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586577237760] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:61657] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.242776 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.242818 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.242828 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.242843 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting not-svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.242854 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] [client 192.168.100.120:51105] Access granted: 'not-svnuser' GET (null)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243059 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243069 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243074 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243080 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting not-svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243104 2021] [authz_svn:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c(450): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] Path to authz file is /usr/local/svn/svn-test/authzsvn.conf
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243190 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] [client 192.168.100.120:51105] Access granted: 'not-svnuser' GET svn-test:/branches
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243215 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243220 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243224 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243231 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting not-svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243235 2021] [authz_svn:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c(450): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] Path to authz file is /usr/local/svn/svn-test/authzsvn.conf
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243238 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] [client 192.168.100.120:51105] Access granted: 'not-svnuser' GET svn-test:/tags
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243248 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243251 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243254 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243261 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] mod_authnz_ldap.c(620): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting not-svnuser
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243265 2021] [authz_svn:debug] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c(450): [client 192.168.100.120:51105] Path to authz file is /usr/local/svn/svn-test/authzsvn.conf
[Tue Jul 20 21:57:52.243274 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195902:tid 140586619234048] [client 192.168.100.120:51105] Access granted: 'not-svnuser' GET svn-test:/trunk
```

## case 3 error_log

```
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:55.187406 2021] [authz_svn:info] [pid 195900:tid 140586669557504] [client 192.168.100.120:56967] Access granted: - GET (null)
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:55.187474 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586669557504] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:56967] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:55.187484 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586669557504] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:56967] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:58.763087 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586635986688] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:56967] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group cn=svn-users,ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:58.763150 2021] [authz_core:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586635986688] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.100.120:56967] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:58.763159 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586635986688] mod_authnz_ldap.c(523): [client 192.168.100.120:56967] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.100.110/ou=People,dc=my,dc=svn,dc=local?uid
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:58.765260 2021] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 195900:tid 140586635986688] mod_authnz_ldap.c(561): [client 192.168.100.120:56967] AH01694: auth_ldap authenticate: user svnuser authentication failed; URI /svn/svn-test/ [ldap_simple_bind() to check user credentials failed][Invalid credentials] (not authoritative)
[Tue Jul 20 21:55:58.765297 2021] [authn_core:error] [pid 195900:tid 140586635986688] [client 192.168.100.120:56967] AH01796: AuthType Basic configured without corresponding module
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing AuthzBasicAuthoritative and setting AuthzLDAPBindAuthoritative = on.

That way auth should fail immediately without trying to fall through to any other auth mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed AuthBasicAuthoritative  and add AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative, so case 3 was solved!

And I found case 2 solution, I'm trying it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996719/apache-svn-authorize-to-active-directory-group